# Random driver expression for automated blinking

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I have a character with eyes.

[image]

I have a blink shapekey. and I am using this expression as a driver to randomly blink on certain frames

```
noise.random() > 0.97
```

[image]

But the blinking is a bit abrupt. I wish I could do it over three frames instead of one.
Is there some way to get random blinking in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom functions instead of simple expressions in your driver. There you can realise more complex behaviours.

Head to the `Scripting` tab and run this script (see [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#custom-function-square-value)):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import noise

def blink_longer():

    # still blinking
    if blink_longer.time > 0:
        blink_longer.time -= 1
        return True
    # new blink?
    elif noise.random() > 0.97:
        blink_longer.time = 3 # max blink time
        return True
    # not blinking
    else:
        return False

blink_longer.time = 0  # avoid a global to track blinking

# add blink function to the driver namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['blink_longer'] = blink_longer
```

Side note: I added an attribute to the function to avoid a global, but globals will work too.

Now in your driver expression, just call the function `blink_longer()` et voila, longer blinking.

**Edit:** Based on @HarryMcKenzie's comment, some notes about usage:  because driver functions drive something (i.e. values) they must return the driven value. In the screenshot i added a custom function

```
def func():
    print("func")
```

to the driver namespace by running the script (note that this action works as `func` itself is valid python). But using this function in a driver results in `ERROR: Invalid Python expression` which my be confusing. By checking the error with `Window > Toggle System Console` one can see that "func" is correctly printed (thus `func` has been called) and *after that* a type error occures. The driven weight value of the shape key is a number but `func` returns implicitly `None`, hence the error. `func` needs to return something number compatible in this case. The `blink_longer` function returns `True/False` which is ok as `True/False` are coerced to $1/0$ respectively. After fixing errors, run the namespace script again to override the old function definition and then refresh the driver expression.

[image]

Comment: +1 very good to know with the namespace thing to prevent global namespace pollution. but can you post a screenshot to be more specific on the usage? because i tried it and i get error https://snipboard.io/h67y8n.jpg I already ran the script but still not detected.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie When you check the console, you will see `TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType` because your `myfunc` doesn't return anything (thus `None`). Returning `True/False` as in my example is ok as its get coerced to $0/1$. I'll update my answer.

Comment: oh yeah how noob of me. i was only interested in the print statement haha. thanks perfect!

Comment: I still edited my answer as i think its useful for erm.. noobs struggling xD

Comment: yes very good especially for beginners. btw it's True=1, False=0, which is different from return Success=0 and return Fail>0 :D

Comment: Darn, you got me. Haha nice catch^^

Comment: Thanks! I dunno why i didn't get a notification for your answer. 

I didn't know we could call custom python functions like this! Lemme double check that this works when I get home tomorrow and then I'll get you the green check mark.